# Not enough disk space for CUDA Toolkit?

Tags: nvidia, cuda

Tried repeatedly to install latest Nvidia CUDA 9.1 Toolkit but always get a 'not enough disk space' error at the end, even if I target external drive with over 400GB available! What gives?

If I run df -h in the command line I see

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

udev             32G     0   32G   0% /dev

tmpfs           6.3G  147M  6.2G   3% /run

/dev/sdb2        40G   35G  2.4G  94% /

tmpfs            32G   55M   32G   1% /dev/shm

tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock

tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup

/dev/sdb3       630G   54G  545G   9% /home

/dev/sdb1       549M  5.8M  544M   2% /boot/efi

tmpfs           6.3G   52K  6.3G   1% /run/user/1000

/dev/sda1       1.9T  1.5T  427G  78% /media/jim/Seagate_1
```

Comment: Show exactly which commands you entered to install things and exactly the output or the last lines of it if too long (as text, not as a picture). Try also `df -i` to see if you do not have a problem with free inodes.

Comment: Looks like `/dev/sdb2` low on space.